# Insert only unique objects into list

Tags: python, django

I have queryset of people:

```
people = Person.objects.all()
```

and I have a list `un_people = []` - meaning a list of people with unique name.

So, there can be more than one person with the same name. i want to filter for this and then insert into list so that list only contains person objects with unique name.

I tried:

```
for person in people: 
   if person.name in un_people:
      #... ?
```

but in list, there are objects, not names. how can I check for objects with same name and then insert into list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `dict` to do the uniqueness, then take the values, eg:

```
uniq_names = {person.name:person for person in people}
uniq_people = uniq_names.values() # use list(unique_names.values()) for Py 3.x
```

Comment: beautiful!. ``.values()`` gives me the whole object again?

Comment: @doniyor just to note this will give you one `People` per name - which I'm guessing is what you're after eg: `Tom, Jon, Jon` will give you `Tom, Jon`. If you're after people that have a *unique* name - eg, doesn't appear more than once eg: `Tom, Jon, Jon` should just give `Tim`, that's something different...

Comment: i need the 1st one. i am now shaping your answer to my need.

Comment: @doniyor *phew* - the 2nd one isn't quite so straight forward :)

Comment: yeah, if I needed the 2nd one, I would do multiple steps to achieve it :).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` data structure:

```
un_people = set(people)
```

If your elements are not hashable as, JonClemens, suggests you can build a list of names first:

```
un_people = set([p.name for p in people])
```

Comment: Presuming a `People` object is hashable, it's unlikely it's going to be on the `.name` attribute that's wanted by the OP.

Comment: @JonClements In that case he can build an intermediate list of names

Comment: @doniyor To recover the Person itself you need a solution as JonClemments has posted and his should be the accepted answer. At the beginning I did not understand that you needed the `Person` objects.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo yeah sorry man, now I updated my question. thanks